# Http server received multiple sockets from one client

Tags: sockets, http

I am writing my own http server using C++. The server has a listener binding to the port `9999`. By default, I use HTTP 1.1 with keep-alive. The server uses `select` to multiplex the IO.

My question is, when I open the browser at `localhost:9999`, I saw multiple sockets being created from the listener. The first request is`GET / HTTP 1.1` and my response is the `index.html` file so the client can open it. Here is a sketch of this `index.html`

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myproject">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/myproject.min.css">
  </head>

    <script src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular-route-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    ....
```

When the client receives this `index.html`, it in turn creates multiple requests asking for `bootstrap.min.css`, `myproject.min.css`, and all the remaining javascript files (`jquery-3.2.1.min.js`, etc). This is what I saw from the server's listener:

```
incoming http connection created on socket 6 <-- initial request (asking '/' and `favicon`)
server sends index.html through 6
incoming http connection created on socket 7 <-- request for bootstrap.min.css
server sends bootstrap.min.css through 7
incoming http connection created on socket 8 <-- request for myproject.min.css
server sends myproject.min.css through 8
incoming http connection created on socket 9 <-- request for jquery-3.2.1.min.js
server sends jquery-3.2.1.min.js through 9
.... (sockets 6, 7, 8, 9 are alive)
```

It does not make any sense to me for client to create a new socket connection for each individual request. I am sure I turn on the `keep-alive` in both response and request. I expected there is only one socket being created, which is `6` in this example, and all the following requests should reuse that socket instead of creating a new one. Am I missing something?

Comment: Even with keep-alive enabled browsers are free to open multiple connections to download multiple resources in parallel.

Comment: Then what is the point of using Keep-Alive?

Comment: @Jes keep-alive simply allows the client to reuse an existing TCP connection for multiple requests, but requests over that connection are still processed serially 1 at a time. Multiple connections allow multiple requests to be processed in parallel. HTTP2 solved this with multiplexing requests over a single connection, but HTTP1 doesn't support that